# 2 matrix norm greater than maximum absolute value

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

how would I prove that, given a matrix A, the maximum absolute value is less than or equal to the 2-norm of that matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Apply Cauchy Schwarz on
$$ e_i^T A e_j. $$